# CSOM move the files one folder another folder

Tags: client-object-model

I have to all files from one folder another folder using CSOM and C#
Thanks for your replay Huge Wood

my code is below

```
var targetSite = new Uri("https://hello.com//teams/Worldwide_Site");
            string src = @"/teams/Worldwide_Site/Shared Documents/BI/Reports/march";
            string dest = @"/teams/Worldwide_Site/Shared Documents/BI/Reports/April";
            string lst = "Reports";

            MoveFiles(targetSite, lst, src, dest);

public static void MoveFiles(Uri url, string listTitle, string srcFolder,string destFolder)
        {

            using (var context = new ClientContext(url))
            {
                var login = "hello.com";
                var password = "xyz";
                var securePassword = new SecureString();
                foreach (char c in password)
                {
                    securePassword.AppendChar(c);
                }
                context.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(login, securePassword);
                var srcList = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(listTitle);
                var qry = CamlQuery.CreateAllItemsQuery();
                qry.FolderServerRelativeUrl = srcFolder;
                var srcItems = srcList.GetItems(qry);
                context.Load(srcItems, icol => icol.Include
                    (i => i.FileSystemObjectType,
                        i => i.File));
                context.ExecuteQuery();

                foreach (var item in srcItems)
                {
                    if (item.FileSystemObjectType == FileSystemObjectType.File)
                    {
                        var destFileUrl = string.Format("{0}/{1}/{2}", listTitle, destFolder, item.File.Name);
                        item.File.MoveTo(destFileUrl, MoveOperations.Overwrite);
                        context.ExecuteQuery();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

I'm getting the issue in  context.ExecuteQuery error like Folder "April" is not found as per my understood destination path is not correct but where I did wrong?

Comment: Hi Sriven, are you able to expand on this into a proper question please.

Answer (score 5):

In order to move the single file to the specified destination URL use [File.MoveTo method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.client.file.moveto%28v=office.15%29.aspx).

---

There is no built-in method in SharePoint CSOM API for moving `Folder` with `Files` from one location into another.

The following solution demonstrates how to move files from source folder into destination folder:

```
public static class FolderExtensions
{


    public static void MoveFilesTo(this Folder folder, string folderUrl)
    {
        var ctx = (ClientContext)folder.Context;
        if (!ctx.Web.IsPropertyAvailable("ServerRelativeUrl"))
        {
            ctx.Load(ctx.Web, w => w.ServerRelativeUrl);   
        }
        ctx.Load(folder, f => f.Files, f => f.ServerRelativeUrl, f => f.Folders);
        ctx.ExecuteQuery();

        //Ensure target folder exists
        ctx.Web.EnsureFolder(folderUrl.Replace(ctx.Web.ServerRelativeUrl, string.Empty));
        foreach (var file in folder.Files)
        {
            var targetFileUrl = file.ServerRelativeUrl.Replace(folder.ServerRelativeUrl, folderUrl);
            file.MoveTo(targetFileUrl, MoveOperations.Overwrite);
        }
        ctx.ExecuteQuery();

        foreach (var subFolder in folder.Folders)
        {
            var targetFolderUrl = subFolder.ServerRelativeUrl.Replace(folder.ServerRelativeUrl,folderUrl);
            subFolder.MoveFilesTo(targetFolderUrl);
        }
    }

}

static class WebExtensions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Ensures whether the folder exists   
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="web"></param>
    /// <param name="folderUrl"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static Folder EnsureFolder(this Web web, string folderUrl)
    {
        return EnsureFolderInternal(web.RootFolder, folderUrl);
    }


    private static Folder EnsureFolderInternal(Folder parentFolder, string folderUrl)
    {
        var ctx = parentFolder.Context;
        var folderNames = folderUrl.Split(new char[] { '/' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        var folderName = folderNames[0];
        var folder = parentFolder.Folders.Add(folderName);
        ctx.Load(folder);
        ctx.ExecuteQuery();

        if (folderNames.Length > 1)
        {
            var subFolderUrl = string.Join("/", folderNames, 1, folderNames.Length - 1);
            return EnsureFolderInternal(folder, subFolderUrl);
        }
        return folder;
    }
}
```

Key points:

- allows to ensure whether destination folder(s) exists
- In case of nested folders, its structure is preserved while moving files

**Usage**

```
var srcFolderUrl = "/news/pages";
var destFolderUrl = "/news/archive/pages";
using (var ctx = new ClientContext(url))
{      
    var sourceFolder = ctx.Web.GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl(srcFolderUrl);
    sourceFolder.MoveFilesTo(destFolderUrl);
    sourceFolder.DeleteObject(); // delete source folder if nessesary
    ctx.ExecuteQuery();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

> The biggest challenge with this application is that the client OM is
>   very limited when it comes to moving documents, and because the need
>   exists to move documents across site collections we can’t take
>   advantage of the MoveTo methods.

See this [blog(SharePoint 2010 : Using The Client Object Model To Move Files And Folders Across Site Collections And Subsites)](http://blog.blumshapiro.com/2012/08/sharepoint-2010-using-the-client-object-model-to-move-files-and-folders-across-site-collections-and-subsites/) for detail

```
public static void CopyDocuments(string srcUrl, string destUrl, string srcLibrary, string destLibrary, Login _login)
    {
        // set up the src client
        SP.ClientContext srcContext = new SP.ClientContext(srcUrl);
        srcContext.AuthenticationMode = SP.ClientAuthenticationMode.FormsAuthentication;
        srcContext.FormsAuthenticationLoginInfo = new SP.FormsAuthenticationLoginInfo(_login.UserName, _login.Password);

        // set up the destination context (in your case there is no needs to create a new context, because it would be the same library!!!!)
        SP.ClientContext destContext = new SP.ClientContext(destUrl);
        destContext.AuthenticationMode = SP.ClientAuthenticationMode.FormsAuthentication;
        destContext.FormsAuthenticationLoginInfo = new SP.FormsAuthenticationLoginInfo(_login.UserName, _login.Password);

        // get the list and items
        SP.Web srcWeb = srcContext.Web;
        SP.List srcList = srcWeb.Lists.GetByTitle(srcLibrary);
        SP.ListItemCollection col = srcList.GetItems(new SP.CamlQuery());
        srcContext.Load(col);
        srcContext.ExecuteQuery();

        // get the new list
        SP.Web destWeb = destContext.Web;
        destContext.Load(destWeb);
        destContext.ExecuteQuery();

        foreach (var doc in col)
        {
            try
            {
                if (doc.FileSystemObjectType == SP.FileSystemObjectType.File)
                {
                    // get the file
                    SP.File f = doc.File;
                    srcContext.Load(f);
                    srcContext.ExecuteQuery();

                    // build new location url
                    string nLocation = destWeb.ServerRelativeUrl.TrimEnd('/') + "/" + destLibrary.Replace(" ", "") + "/" + f.Name;

                    // read the file, copy the content to new file at new location
                    SP.FileInformation fileInfo = SP.File.OpenBinaryDirect(srcContext, f.ServerRelativeUrl);
                    SP.File.SaveBinaryDirect(destContext, nLocation, fileInfo.Stream, true);
                } 

                if (doc.FileSystemObjectType == SP.FileSystemObjectType.Folder)
                {
                    // load the folder
                    srcContext.Load(doc);
                    srcContext.ExecuteQuery();

                    // get the folder data, get the file collection in the folder
                    SP.Folder folder = srcWeb.GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl(doc.FieldValues["FileRef"].ToString());
                    SP.FileCollection fileCol = folder.Files;

                    // load everyting so we can access it
                    srcContext.Load(folder);
                    srcContext.Load(fileCol);
                    srcContext.ExecuteQuery();

                    foreach (SP.File f in fileCol)
                    {
                        // load the file
                        srcContext.Load(f);
                        srcContext.ExecuteQuery();

                        string[] parts = null;
                        string id = null;

                        if (srcLibrary == "My Files")
                        {
                            // these are doc sets
                            parts = f.ServerRelativeUrl.Split('/');
                            id = parts[parts.Length - 2];
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            id = folder.Name;
                        }

                        // build new location url
                        string nLocation = destWeb.ServerRelativeUrl.TrimEnd('/') + "/" + destLibrary.Replace(" ", "") + "/" + id + "/" + f.Name;

                        // read the file, copy the content to new file at new location
                        SP.FileInformation fileInfo = SP.File.OpenBinaryDirect(srcContext, f.ServerRelativeUrl);
                        SP.File.SaveBinaryDirect(destContext, nLocation, fileInfo.Stream, true);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Log("File Error = " + ex.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: this is a great function, ty

Answer (score 0):

I got the same 'folder not found' issue when using this approach

```
item.File.MoveTo(destFileUrl, MoveOperations.Overwrite);
```

When i get the file object using GetFileByServerRelativeUrl method it works fine

```
File fileItem = web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl(item["FileRef"].ToString());
context.Load(fileItem);
context.ExecuteQuery();

string sourceFolder = item["FileDirRef"].ToString();
string targetFilePath = item["FileRef"].ToString().Replace(sourceFolder, destinationFolder);
fileItem.MoveTo(targetFilePath, MoveOperations.Overwrite);

context.ExecuteQuery();
```

I know it's old thread but i just got the same issue and managed to resolve it. So i would like to share.