# How to get SP.File from _layouts/.../images/

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin

I have to implement file copying, in some case i need to copy file using **CSOM** (for. ex. /_layouts/15/images/itgen.png - default small list icon) into my library.
What i have tried is:

- get by SP.Web.getFileByServerRelativeUrl()
- XMLHttpRequest/jQuery.get - but IE 9 does not support Blobs.

Is there any another way to do that?
Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can still copy it old school way: Read file content!

```
    getFile: function (filePath) {
    var deferred = jQuery.Deferred();
    var req = jQuery.ajax({
        url: filePath,
        type: "GET",
        cache: false
    }).done(function (fileContents) {
        if (fileContents !== undefined && fileContents.length > 0) {
            deferred.resolve(fileContents);
        } else {
            deferred.reject('Failed to read file from web..');
        }

    }).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
        deferred.reject("Request for web file failed: " + textStatus);
    });

    return deferred.promise();
},
uploadFileToHost: function (filePath, destinationPath, fileName) {
    var deferred = jQuery.Deferred();
    getFile(filePath).then(
        function (contents) {
            var context = file.context
            var createInfo = new SP.FileCreationInformation();
            createInfo.set_content(new SP.Base64EncodedByteArray());
            for (var i = 0; i < contents.length; i++) {

                createInfo.get_content().append(contents.charCodeAt(i));
            }
            createInfo.set_overwrite(true);
            createInfo.set_url(destinationPath+fileName);
            var files = context.get_web().getFolderByServerRelativeUrl(destinationPath).get_files();
            context.load(files);
            files.add(createInfo);

            context.executeQueryAsync(
                function () {
                    deferred.resolve();
                },
                function (sender, args) {
                    deferred.reject(args.get_message());
                });
        },
        function (err) {
            deferred.reject(err);
        }
    );

    deferred.done(function () {
        Helper.logMessage("Uploaded to Host : " + file.destinationFileName);
    });
    deferred.fail(function (error) {
        Helper.logMessage("Failed to uploaded to Host : '" + file.destinationFileName + "'. Error : " + error);
    });

    return deferred.promise();
},
```

Comment: thanks a lot for this solution!
we had to support IE9 (I wrote about it above).
My solution is pretty close to yours, but i use Image  element to load image and then Canvas for drawind image on it and Canvas.toDataURL() method, which IE 9 supports (oh, at least something :)).

Answer (score 1):

For those searching for the answer to the TITLE of this post, no, you cannot get an `SPFile` (or client equivalent `SP.File`) that represents a file in any virtual directory (/_layouts, /_images, /_vti_bin, etc).

The reason being is that an `SPFile` is tied to an `SPListItem`, which lives in an `SPList`. All of these objects live in the content database (witchcraft takes place for ghosted files, but they still live in a library).

Answer (score -2):

here are some samples:

! **[CSOM move the files one folder another folder](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/97009/csom-move-the-files-one-folder-another-folder)**

http://www.postseek.com/meta/a6c1a29023b78254f93e543ca769e5b0
http://zimmergren.net/technical/sp-2010-uploading-files-using-the-client-om-in-sharepoint-2010

Comment: Please don't post link-only answers, instead add substantial part of the posts/blogs in your answer.