# Getting (400) Bad Request error while moving files from one folder to another folder in same document library using CSOM

Tags: sharepoint-online, client-object-model, csom

I have a console application in which I am trying to move files from one folder to another folder in same document library using CSOM. While doing so I am getting below error:

> (400) Bad Request

I have taken reference from [this](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/97009/csom-move-the-files-one-folder-another-folder) post

My code is as below:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;
using ClientOM = Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;

namespace ConsoleApp2
{
    public static class FolderExtensions
    {
        public static void MoveFilesTo(this Folder folder, string folderUrl)
        {
            var ctx = (ClientContext)folder.Context;

        //SecureString passWord = new SecureString();
        //foreach (char c in "HelloWorld@1234".ToCharArray()) passWord.AppendChar(c);
        //ctx.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials("jay.desai@companyname.com", passWord);

        if (!ctx.Web.IsPropertyAvailable("https://company.sharepoint.com"))
        {
            ctx.Load(ctx.Web, w => w.ServerRelativeUrl);
        }
        ctx.Load(folder, f => f.Files, f => f.ServerRelativeUrl, f => f.Folders);
        ctx.ExecuteQuery();

        //Ensure target folder exists
        //ctx.Web.EnsureFolder(folderUrl.Replace(ctx.Web.ServerRelativeUrl, string.Empty));
        foreach (var file in folder.Files)
        {
            var targetFileUrl = file.ServerRelativeUrl.Replace(folder.ServerRelativeUrl, folderUrl);
            file.MoveTo(targetFileUrl, MoveOperations.Overwrite);
        }
        ctx.ExecuteQuery();

       }
    }

//static class WebExtensions
//{
//    /// <summary>
//    /// Ensures whether the folder exists   
//    /// </summary>
//    /// <param name="web"></param>
//    /// <param name="folderUrl"></param>
//    /// <returns></returns>
//    public static Folder EnsureFolder(this Web web, string folderUrl)
//    {
//        return EnsureFolderInternal(web.RootFolder, folderUrl);
//    }


//    private static Folder EnsureFolderInternal(Folder parentFolder, string folderUrl)
//    {
//        var ctx = parentFolder.Context;
//        var folderNames = folderUrl.Split(new char[] { '/' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
//        var folderName = folderNames[0];
//        var folder = parentFolder.Folders.Add(folderName);
//        ctx.Load(folder);
//        ctx.ExecuteQuery();

//        if (folderNames.Length > 1)
//        {
//            var subFolderUrl = string.Join("/", folderNames, 1, folderNames.Length - 1);
//            return EnsureFolderInternal(folder, subFolderUrl);
//        }
//        return folder;
//    }
//}

 class Program
 {

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var srcFolderUrl = "/sites/DataServices/Shared Documents/Data Dictionaries";
        var destFolderUrl = "/sites/DataServices/Shared Documents/Data Dictionaries/Archive";
        using (var ctx = new ClientContext("https://companyname.sharepoint.com"))
        {
            var sourceFolder = ctx.Web.GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl(srcFolderUrl);
            sourceFolder.MoveFilesTo(destFolderUrl);
            ctx.ExecuteQuery();
        }
    }  
  }
}
```

I am getting error at `ctx.ExecuteQuery();`
[image]

Answer (score 0):

@Jay Desai,

Can you point which line prompts this error?

And i think below code should be:

```
if (!ctx.Web.IsPropertyAvailable("https://company.sharepoint.com"))
```

==>  `if (!ctx.Web.IsPropertyAvailable("ServerRelativeUrl"))`

Besides, when you generate a client context, the site URL should be the site where the targeted folder located at.

Below is my test demo, it works on My SPO library.

```
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace TeamifySharePointClassicSite.moveFolder
{
    class FolderExtensionsapp
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var srcFolderUrl = "/sites/testprivate/mytestdoclib/Data Dictionaries";
            var destFolderUrl = "/sites/testprivate/mytestdoclib/Data Dictionaries/Archive";

            var password = "xxxxxxxxx";
            var username = "admin@abc.onmicrosoft.com";
            string SiteUrl = "https://abc.sharepoint.com/sites/testprivate";
            SecureString securestring = new SecureString();
            password.ToCharArray().ToList().ForEach(s => securestring.AppendChar(s));        
            
            using (var ctx = new ClientContext(SiteUrl))
            {
                ctx.Credentials= new SharePointOnlineCredentials(username, securestring);
                var sourceFolder = ctx.Web.GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl(srcFolderUrl);
                sourceFolder.MoveFilesTo(destFolderUrl);
                ctx.ExecuteQuery();
            }

        }
    }

    public static class FolderExtensions
    {
        public static void MoveFilesTo(this Folder folder, string folderUrl)
        {
            var ctx = (ClientContext)folder.Context;
            if (!ctx.Web.IsPropertyAvailable("ServerRelativeUrl"))
            {
                ctx.Load(ctx.Web, w => w.ServerRelativeUrl);
            }
            ctx.Load(folder, f => f.Files, f => f.ServerRelativeUrl, f => f.Folders);
            ctx.ExecuteQuery();

            //Ensure target folder exists
            ctx.Web.EnsureFolder(folderUrl.Replace(ctx.Web.ServerRelativeUrl, string.Empty));
            foreach (var file in folder.Files)
            {
                var targetFileUrl = file.ServerRelativeUrl.Replace(folder.ServerRelativeUrl, folderUrl);
                file.MoveTo(targetFileUrl, MoveOperations.Overwrite);
            }
            ctx.ExecuteQuery();

            //foreach (var subFolder in folder.Folders)
            //{
            //    var targetFolderUrl = subFolder.ServerRelativeUrl.Replace(folder.ServerRelativeUrl, folderUrl);
            //    subFolder.MoveFilesTo(targetFolderUrl);
            //}
        }

    }

    static class WebExtensions
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Ensures whether the folder exists   
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="web"></param>
        /// <param name="folderUrl"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static Folder EnsureFolder(this Web web, string folderUrl)
        {
            return EnsureFolderInternal(web.RootFolder, folderUrl);
        }


        private static Folder EnsureFolderInternal(Folder parentFolder, string folderUrl)
        {
            var ctx = parentFolder.Context;
            var folderNames = folderUrl.Split(new char[] { '/' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            var folderName = folderNames[0];
            var folder = parentFolder.Folders.Add(folderName);
            ctx.Load(folder);
            ctx.ExecuteQuery();

            if (folderNames.Length > 1)
            {
                var subFolderUrl = string.Join("/", folderNames, 1, folderNames.Length - 1);
                return EnsureFolderInternal(folder, subFolderUrl);
            }
            return folder;
        }
    }
}
```

BR

Comment: I'm still getting same error at same line. I have updated my question with error screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

Problem with the configuration of console application. I was using .NET core. Finally when I created console application with .NET Framework it worked.